# Error when loading the .qml file: 'ComboBoxStyle is not a type'

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qt6

I've attempted to use the code from [this answer](https://forum.qt.io/post/534219) within my .qml file, but upon running the application, I encounter the following error message (the application starts but with an empty window):

```
qrc:/app.qml:17:16: ComboBoxStyle is not a type 
             style: ComboBoxStyle { 
                    ^
```

Here's the code:

app.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 200
    title: "Simple ComboBox Example"

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        width: 200
        model: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]
        currentIndex: 0 // Установка начального выбора (первая опция)

        // Стиль ComboBox
        style: ComboBoxStyle {
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering

            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 25
                border.width: 1
            }

            label: Label {
                anchors {
                    fill: parent
                    left: parent.left
                    leftMargin: 5
                }
                font.pixelSize: 12
                text: control.currentText
                verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QUrl url("qrc:/app.qml");

    QQuickView view(url);

    view.show();

    return QGuiApplication::exec();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(QtQmlTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets Quick QuickControls2)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt::Core Qt::Gui Qt::Widgets Qt::Quick Qt::QuickControls2)

qt_add_resources(${PROJECT_NAME} "qml"
        PREFIX "/"
        BASE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
        FILES app.qml)
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: does adding `import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4` solve it ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK now I get the error `module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed`. Maybe some packages are required to install or I should add something in my CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @AhmedAEK by the way, can you edit my question to remove the "tttt", please? :)

Comment: looks like they changed the API between Qt5 and Qt6, see [Customizing ComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-customize.html#customizing-combobox), to edit the question just click on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77769673/edit) button at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @AhmedAEK the site doesn't allow me to remove "tttt". It says that my answer is mainly code. Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAEK the code from the official docs works. I'll take a look at it and try to apply it to my problem.

Comment: There's a big difference between Qt Quick Controls 1 and Qt Quick Controls 2. The ComboBoxStyle object comes from version 1, which was deprecated but still exists in Qt5. It no longer exists in Qt6 though.